# Angular Material DatePicker DD.MM.YYYY

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material2

Was anyone successful with a datepicker with format 'DD.MM.YYYY' and momentjs? I think the documentation as well as the starblitz might be broken.

Here my MaterialModule (which is imported in my AppModule), but all my datepicker have format LL (24.6.2018) instead of DD.MM.YYYY (24.06.2018).

```
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MomentDateModule, MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

export const MY_FORMATS = {
    parse: {
        dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    },
    display: {
        dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        monthYearLabel: 'MM YYYY',
        dateA11yLabel: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY',
    },
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [..., MatDatepickerModule, MomentDateModule, ...],
    exports: [..., MatDatepickerModule, MomentDateModule, ...],
    providers: [
        {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'de'},
        {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
        {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
    ],
})
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods that we can use to customise the date format with MomentJs, as described in [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings):

- Import the `MatMomentDateModule` in your application's root module, then provide `MAT_DATE_FORMATS` in main module or at component level:

```ts
import {MatMomentDateModule} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

// ..

const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    monthYearLabel: 'MM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY',
  },
};

// ..

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule
  ],
  provide: [
     { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
  ]
})
```

**Example**:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzicfk

---

- If importing `MatMomentDateModule` is not possible, we can use the `MomentDateAdapter` for `DateAdapter` provider, together with `MAT_DATE_FORMATS`:

```ts
import {MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

// ..

@NgModule({
  provide: [
     { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS },
     { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] }
  ]
})
```

**Example**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uzicfk-8y2lwr

*Examples are build on Angular Material v9*